# Installing Xamarin in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, installation, visual-studio-2022

"After I attempted to install Xamarin in Visual Studio community 2022, it displayed the following errors:

Installing Xamarin problem: After nine attempts, there was a problem downloading the following file: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2223648.

Sorry, something went wrong. Couldn't download AndroidPlatformTools_Xamarin.

Couldn't download AndroidPlatformMAUI.

Couldn't download AndroidBuildTools_Xamarin.

Couldn't download AndroidForm31.

Couldn't download AndroidTools_Xamarin."

please help me I can't install the Xamarin to my visual studio community 2022.

I would greatly appreciated your help.

Comment: I can download that file, likely a network issue.

Comment: If you have a nearby friend with a better connection, ask them to generate the offline installer and then move it through a portable drive https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/create-an-offline-installation-of-visual-studio?view=vs-2022#use-the-command-line-to-create-a-local-layout, remember to include the cross platform workload https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/workload-component-id-vs-community?view=vs-2022&preserve-view=true#net-multi-platform-app-ui-development

Comment: What's the error message ? maybe a proxy issue ?

Comment: Thank you, guys. I appreciate your help. I love you, bro. I fixed the problem; it was because of a network issue. I've already installed Xamarin. <3